# Grabbing HTML + <script> from another page using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a button on a page which when clicked, loads a `<div>` from another file.

```
<div id="main">
    <button name="grab">grab</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button[name="grab"]').click(function() {
                $(#newarea).load("./page.php div#info");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="newarea">
    </div>
</div>
```

`page.php` has a `<script>` inside the loaded `<div>`:

```
<div id="info">
   lorem ipsum
   dolor
   <script>
      ...
   </script>
</div>
```

...but inspecting element on the loaded element shows the `<script>` is not loaded. This is what it looks like after the button is clicked:

```
<div id="main">
    <button name="grab">grab</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button[name="grab"]').click(function() {
                $(#newarea).load("./page.php div#info");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div id="newarea">
        lorem ipsum
        dolor
    </div>
</div>
```

Note the `<script>` on `page.php` is not loaded. How do I grab not only the HTML, but also the Javascript found on another page using JQuery `.load` or an alternative?

Comment: What do you get if you use `.load` now?

Comment: @MorHaviv I've added what page source looks like when the button is clicked.

Comment: Is it an option to use php instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution) documentation explains this in detail:

> **Script Execution**
>
> When calling `.load()` using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to `.html()` prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If `.load()` is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will successfully execute.
>
> `1 | $( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );`
>
> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> `1 | $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );`

You're using a *selector expression* so the script tag won't be executed and instead will be stripped.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. I had figured since the `<script>` is inside the `<div>` it would carry forward.

Comment: @gator I would have thought so as well. Surprisingly though, it gets stripped.

Answer (score 1):

How about inserting a callback function that inserts the `<script>` tag?

```
<div id="main">
    <button name="grab">grab</button>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('button[name="grab"]').click(function() {
                $('#newarea').load("./page.php div#info",function(){
                  var $script = $('<script></script>');
                  $script.attr('src','URLOFTHESCRIPTFILE');
                  $('#newarea').append($script)
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</div>
```